# EJB Security not being checked

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb

I am trying to secure all of my ejb's, and have added them to the "other" domain.

My jboss-ejb3.xml file has:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss:ejb-jar
xmlns:jboss="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:1.2"
xmlns:sec="urn:security"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd
    urn:security urn:security"
version="3.1"
impl-version="2.0">
<assembly-descriptor>
    <sec:security>
        <ejb-name>*</ejb-name>
        <sec:security-domain>other</sec:security-domain>
    </sec:security>
</assembly-descriptor>
```

I have noticed that my security constraints are not being honored(things like @RolesAllowed). My question is:

-Do I have to have an ejb-jar.xml file in order to use the `<ejb-name>*</ejb-name>` declaration? Or what could be the problem?

Comment: what other configuration have you done? where have you the other security domain defined? which jboss version you have?

Comment: I think I see what is happening but I'm unsure how to fix it. I am running IT tests, and using a Context to make the calls to the ejb methods. The 1st call works as expected. Then, the 2nd call requires a different role, so I get a new Initial Context and pass in the updated credentials. However, when I ask the ejb who it thinks I am, it still thinks I am in the old role.

Comment: Which JBoss version are you using? Could you post the lookup code as well?